# Can program crashes during development affect my system's security?

Tags: security

I have been using Ubuntu for some time, and I loved it! I'm feeling way more safe now.

But, I'm a Computer Science Student, and I have to code a lot. And I have been creating various codes, and it caused a lot of Segmentation faults, stack overflows, stack smashes, etc.

I have been wondering, does this errors can cause any harm to the memory of the OS or creating something like a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program runs in a especially allocated space in memory. A segfault, stack overflow, etc. happens inside this space.

When you run your programs normally, these errors won't affect anything else. All these errors happen on the RAM btw., not on persistent memory.

So you won't compromise your computer with stuff like this. (Unless you're doing some buggy file I/O as root..., which you probably shouldn't during development)

Comment: That's good a to know. Thank you for answering me.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "buggy file I/O"? I mean, I'm currently programming in C, and I'm using malloc.

Comment: If you're writing to files on the FS **as root**, you may accidentally harm your system, if it doesn't work quite well. So just don't run your programs as root, if not necessary.